# Showing a result starting from Fatou's lemma

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, proof-writing, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

I know the following formulation of the Fatou's lemma:

> *From Jacod-Protter (2004)*
> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of random variables defined on it.
> If the random variables $X_n$ satisfy $X_n\geq Y$ a.s. $(Y\in\mathcal{L}^1)$, all $n$, we have $$E\{\liminf_{n\to\infty}X_n\}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}E\{X_n\}\tag{1}$$In particular, if $X_n\geq 0$ a.s. all $n$, then $$E\{\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\}\leq\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}E\{X_n\}\tag{2}$$

Given the above result, how is that possible to show that:

> $$\displaystyle\mathbb{E}( {\limsup_{n \mathop \to \infty} X_n}) \ge \limsup_{n \mathop \to \infty} \mathbb{E}({X_n})\tag{3}$$

? If so, how?

Comment: Try Fatou with $Y-X_n$

Comment: But how to pass from expectation of limit to probability of limit? @Shaqinho

Comment: At the risk of asking something stupid, what is $E_n$?

Comment: No problem at all. Just a silly error of mine, I will immediately edit, thank you! @zugzug

Comment: Is there missing information? In the edit, I see that $E_n$ was changed to $X_n$. But $\limsup X_n$ is not an event so taking the probability doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. The probabilities should change to expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use the fact that $\liminf (-X_n)=-\limsup X_n.$ So then
\begin{align}
&\phantom{\implies} E(\liminf (-X_n))=E(-\limsup(X_n))=-E(\limsup(X_n))\\
&\leq \liminf E(-X_n)=\liminf(-E(X_n))=-\limsup(E(X_n)).
\end{align}
Then just flip the inequalities. Typically the assumption to justify this is that $|X_n|\leq Y$. Then $-Y\leq X_n \leq Y$. In particular, $-X_n\geq -Y$, so Fatou's is justified applied to $-X_n$.